# Execute legacy SSIS packages on newer SQL version

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dts

I have a few SSIS packages, developed in SQL Server 2008. Those packages have ActiveX Script Task. When I try to open those packages in VS 2017, it throws an error, saying ActiveX task is deprecated. Converting those task to Script Task would be really time consuming.

Is there a way to execute those packages in SQL Server Agent? We use SQL Server 2016 Standard edition.

I tried executing from the file system, but it also throws an error:

> The "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ActiveXScriptTask.ActiveXScriptTask, Microsoft.SqlServer.ActiveXScriptTask, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" task has been deprecated and cannot be used with this version of Integration Services.

I don't really need for now to upgrade those packages, I can still use Business Intelligence 2008 to maintain them. I just need them to run on the SQL Server 2016 instance.

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: There is no backward compaitibility in SSIS; you need to upgrade the packages to the relevant version in deployment process in Visual Studio. If that means that they have features that have been remvoed, you will need to update the packages if you want to use them on a supported version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, SQL Server is telling you the answer in the error message quite simply.

It is Deprecated and cannot be used.